# AngularJs/Bootstrap - Bind checkbox in list not works properly

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a roles list that filter a permissions list. The permissions list has a checkbox indicating that it is selected.

Each role has a list of associated permissions. When a role is selected, all available permissions are displayed and those already associated with them will be checked. By clicking on the checkbox of each permission you can associate or desesociate it.

But the select and unselect permission action does not work properly. I can not figure out what the problem. Can someone help me ? Thanks!!!

[Code in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cqBqp6AETCpXk94iAWtJ?p=preview)

Page code

```
 <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="list-group">
                <a ng-click="selectRole(role)" ng-repeat="role in model.roles" class="list-group-item" ng-class="{active: role.id == model.selectedRole.id}">{{role.name}}</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="list-group">
                <a ng-repeat="permission in model.permissions" class="list-group-item">{{permission.name}}                  <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" ng-checked="isSelected(permission.id) > -1" ng-click="clickPermission(permission)" ng-class="{active: permission.id == model.selectedPermission.id}" />
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Controller code

```
app.controller('PermissionsToRoleController', function($scope) {

  $scope.model = {
    roles: [],
    permissions: [],
    selectedRole: null,
        selectedPermission: null
  };  

  $scope.selectRole = function(role) {
    $scope.model.selectedRole = role;
  }

  var findRoles = function() {
    $scope.model.roles = [{id: 1, name: 'ADMIN', permissions: [{id: 1, name:'MASTER'}] },
                          {id: 2, name: 'USER',  permissions: [] }
                         ];

        $scope.model.permissions = [{id: 1, name: 'MASTER'}];

        $scope.model.selectedRole = $scope.model.roles[0];
  };

  $scope.clickPermission = function(permission) {
    $scope.model.selectedPermission = permission;
    var idx = $scope.isSelected(permission.id);
    if (idx > -1) {
      $scope.model.selectedRole.permissions.splice(idx, 1);
    } else {
      $scope.model.selectedRole.permissions.push(permission);
    }
  };

  $scope.isSelected = function(permissionId) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.model.selectedRole.permissions.length ; i++) {
      if ($scope.model.selectedRole.permissions[i].id === permissionId) {
              return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }

  findRoles();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I found being the checkbox, while functions properly, the display won't "uncheck" when you click on it.

This can be fixed by changing the surrounding element to `span` instead of `a`

```
<span ng-repeat="permission in model.permissions" class="list-group-item">{{permission.name}}                  
    <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" ng-checked="isSelected(permission.id) > -1" ng-click="clickPermission(permission)" ng-class="{active: permission.id == model.selectedPermission.id}" />
</span>
```

I'm not sure about the reason behind this, though.

Comment: Each role has a list of associated permissions. When a role is selected, all available permissions are displayed and those already associated with them will be checked. By clicking on the checkbox of each permission you can associate or desesociate it. got it ?